# How do i update a plot inside a loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, plot

I'm measuring the time it takes to solve a linear system. Im comparing the time it takes between the solve and inv linalg functions. This is what i have so far.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for n in (100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000):

    A = np.random.randn(n,n)
    B = np.ones((n,1))
    
    # solving using INV FNC
    
    start_time = datetime.now()
    Xi = np.linalg.inv(A)*B
    end_time = datetime.now()
    
    # solving using SOLVE FNC
    
    start_time2 = datetime.now()
    Xs = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
    end_time2 = datetime.now()
    
   
    print('Duration of INV FNC for n: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print('Duration of SOLVE FNC for n: {}'.format(end_time2 - start_time2))
```

Pretty much I'm not sure how to make a plot that updates inside the loop showing the comparison of the time it takes to solve the different functions. The plot should have n on the x axis (as in size of the matrices), and then the time takes so solve on the y. Im stuck :(

Comment: Why do you need to update it inside the loop? Why not appending the results in a list/array and plotting after you have all the data?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it is to build a list of n (which you have already done in the for loop) and a continually updating list of the solve times.
Before the loop initialise:

```
T1 = []
T2 = []
```

In the loop add to this list the times recorded:

```
T1.append(end_time - start_time)
T2.append(end_time2 - start_time2)
```

and then present the results how you wish, after the loop. For example like this:

````
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.grid()
plt.plot([100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000], T1, label='solve 1 (s)')
plt.plot([100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000], T2, label='solve 2 (s)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()```
````